# Parsing simple civilian time to full date and time using Joda Time

Tags: java, android, time, jodatime

I have a time interval string given as:

```
"04:00 PM - 04:30 PM"
```

My goal is to parse this string using Joda Time to a start and end time variable that look like this:

```
String startTime = "2019-06-11T04:00:00"

String endTime = "2019-06-11T04:30:00"
```

Milliseconds will always be `00`, and I can easily get the current date using the joda time library, but I'm having a lot of difficulty in the full implementation starting from the interval string to the two final strings.

Thanks for any help!

My current attempt was:

```
String[] selectedTime = interval.split(" - ");
DateTimeFormatter parser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
DateTime dtStart = parser.parseDateTime(selectedTime[0]);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
String startTime = formatter.print(dtStart);
```

I understand why this doesn't work, as I'm not passing in all of the required information such as the year, month, date, and milliseconds.

Comment: By the way, only in the US are the terms "civilian time" "military time" used. Much of the planet uses both routinely and refer to them as 12-hour clock and 24-hour clock.

Comment: @BasilBourque good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basil Bourque is correct that you should prefer java.time, the modern Java date and time API, over Joda-Time. In case you are already using Joda-Time a lot and don’t want to upgrade to java.time just now, here’s the Joda-Time solution to your question. **Edit:** I have rewritten the code to take the following comment from you into account:

> …Could you possible provide some assistance regarding how to determine
>   the endtime - time zone? There is such a case where the interval will
>   be from "11:30 PM - 12:00 AM." Now, the current time is 11:30, so the
>   DateTimeZone will return today's date. As I attempt to generate the
>   string for the end time, it's date will be set for today's date, but
>   the final string should have the next day's date because it is
>   reference to 12:00 am.…

```
    String interval = "04:00 PM - 04:30 PM";
    String[] selectedTime = interval.split(" - ");
    DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm a");
    LocalDate today = new LocalDate(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
    LocalTime tStart = parser.parseLocalTime(selectedTime[0]);

    String startTime = today.toLocalDateTime(tStart).toString();
    System.out.println("Start time: " + startTime);
```

When run today output is:

> Start time: 2019-06-12T16:00:00.000

Since 4 PM is 16 on a 24 hour clock, I assumed this was the result you wanted. If you want formatting without milliseconds, just format the `LocalDateTime` you get the same way as you format `dtStart` in your question.

The end time is just a little bit more complicated:

```
    LocalTime tEnd = parser.parseLocalTime(selectedTime[1]);
    String endTime;
    if (tEnd.isBefore(tStart)) {
        // Assume that end time is after midnight, that is, tomorrow
        endTime = today.plusDays(1).toLocalDateTime(tEnd).toString();
    } else {
        // The normal case: both start and end times are today
        endTime = today.toLocalDateTime(tEnd).toString();
    }
    System.out.println("End time: " + endTime);
```

> End time: 2019-06-12T16:30:00.000

If instead we had had

```
    String interval = "11:30 PM - 12:00 AM";
```

> End time: 2019-06-13T00:00:00.000

### Joda-Time is in maintenance mode

A quote from the Joda-Time home page:

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
>   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
>   to `java.time` (JSR-310).

(https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Even if you’re coding for older Android (under API level 26), at least for new code I would prefer a dependency on ThreeTenABP over one on Joda-Time.

Comment: This worked super well! Could you possible provide some assistance regarding how to determine the endtime - time zone? There is such a case where the interval will be from "11:30 PM - 12:00 AM." Now, the current time is 11:30, so the DateTimeZone will return today's date. As I attempt to generate the string for the end time, it's date will be set for today's date, but the final string should have the next day's date because it is reference to 12:00 am. I have been messing around with forOffsetHours/forOffsetHoursMinutes, but have been having unexpected results.

Comment: @BobDuncan I have rewritten the code and added handling of end time. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

## *java.time*

Your inputs lack an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So parse as `LocalDateTime` objects.

Your input text is in standard ISO 8601 format. These standard formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes for generating/parsing strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2019-06-11T04:00:00" ) ;
```

You want only the time-of-day, so extract a `LocalTime` object.

```
LocalTime lt = ldt.toLocalTime() ;
```

Generally best to let the `DateTimeFormatter` class automatically localize for you.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Or Locale.US, Locale.ITALY, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = lt.format( f ) + " — " + otherLt.format( f ) ;
```

Otherwise, specify a particular formatting pattern if you must.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HH:mm a" , Locale.US ) ;
String output = lt.format( f ) + " to " + otherLt.format( f ) ;
```

## Earlier Android

Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

For Android 26 and later, an implementation of *java.time* is built-in.

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]